# Unable to find error in ajax function submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have this function where in **IE8 only** the `alert` doesn't fire and the `ajax` part is not run at all. The form is then submitted despite the `return false`. Why is this happening? Why is it only happening in IE8?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="DownloadForm"]').submit(function(){
        var valCases = new Array()
        valCases.push(($('input[name="firstname"]').val()!="") ? true : false )
        valCases.push(($('input[name="lastname"]').val()!="") ? true : false )
        valCases.push(($('input[name="company"]').val()!="") ? true : false )
        valCases.push(($('input[name="email"]').val()!="") ? true : false )

        alert(valCases.indexOf(false)) //this alert doesn't fire!


        if (valCases.indexOf(false)==-1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //before
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    //do something
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    //error
                }
            });
            return false;
      } else {
            $('.inl-table tr').each(function(index){
                if (index==valCases.indexOf(false)) {
                    $(this).next().children('th').css('color','red');
                }
            });
            return false;
      }
      return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: HTML pls... maybe you miss a submit button. i had this problem once that a browser was ignoring a jquery .submit() becouse of a missing <input type="submit"> in my HTML

Comment: There is a button of type submit in the form.

Comment: why are you not using semicolon to terminate the line? this may be the cause of error and not read in IE. IE is worst browser to read the JS. So add the semicolon and then try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be, that this array function doesn't exist in IE8:

```
valCases.indexOf(false)
```

That won't explain the missing alert, of course :)

EDIT: Ok, I read your code wrong. It explains the missing alert ;)

You'll find a polyfill under this link:
[MDN - Array indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Since you're already using jQuery, you might aswell use `jQuery.inArray` which falls back to a native `indexOf` function when available.

Comment: It would explain the missing alert. If it throws an error trying to do `valCases.indexOf(false)` then the alert isn't going to be displayed.

Comment: This is the error. Using a polyfill to provide the indexOf function for IE8 fixes it.

Comment: The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) has information on providing this functionality for browsers that don't support it. Not sure if you want to include this as part of your answer.

Comment: Not knowing the Array.prototype.indexOf function, ie8 js engine fails building the alert argument, therefore even the alert function is not triggered cause : it throws and escapes before reaching alert execution

Comment: Thanks, @AnthonyGrist. Of course I'll include in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use out the ajax function it:

```
var dd =$(this).serialize();
```

in ajax

```
data :dd,
```